# Error "A Web Part of web form control on this page cannot be displayed ..."

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When adding a custom web part in SharePoint 2010, I get the following error:

> a web part of web form control on this page cannot be displayed or imported the type could not be found or is not registered as safe

It is registered as safe. 
I am site collection administrator and the machine administrator.

I am deploying using the latest Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the webpart assembly is in the GAC or bin. If not - put it in the GAC and do IIS Reset. And that the web.config of the correct web application contains the safecontrol entry for your webpart.